# How to loop through and build an array from each referenced entity

Tags: hooks, paragraphs

I’m trying to create a card grid component using paragraphs.  I have a reference entity which references different card types with unlimited cardinality.  I’m able to pull the values from the reference entity with the below code but this only pulls the initial values so I’m only getting data from one entity instead of each individual entity as they are added to the grid.  I’m not sure why my foreach loop is not working in my preprocess paragraph function, can anyone steer me in the right direction?

```
if ($paragraph->getType() == 'card_grid') {
      if (!$paragraph->field_select_card_type->isEmpty()) {
        $field_select_card_type = $paragraph->field_select_card_type->referencedEntities();
        $card_array = [];
        foreach($field_select_card_type as $key => $card_type) {
          $card_title = "";
          $card_image = "";
          $card_url = "";
          $card_meta_description = "";
$card_type_data = $card_type->get('field_select_a_page')->referencedEntities(); 

$node_id = $card_type_data[0]->id();
          $node_data = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($node_id);

          if($node_data) {
            $card_title = $node_data->title->value;
            if ($node_data->bundle() == "article") {
              $card_image = !$node_data->field_image->isEmpty() ? $node_data->field_image->entity->getFileUri() : "";
            }
            if ($node_data->bundle() == "page") {
              $card_image = !$node_data->field_featured_image->isEmpty() ? $node_data->field_featured_image->entity->getFileUri() : "";
            }
            $card_url = $node_data->toUrl()->toString();
          }

          $card_title = $card_type->field_override_title_->value ? $card_type->field_override_title_->value : $card_title;
          if($card_type->hasField('field_override_image')){
            $card_image = !$card_type->field_override_image->isEmpty() ? $card_type->field_override_image->entity->getFileUri() : $card_image;
          }
          $card_meta_description = $card_type->field_override_meta_description->value ? $card_type->field_override_meta_description->value : $card_meta_description;

          $card_array[$key]['card_title'] = $card_title;
          $card_array[$key]['card_image'] = $card_image;
          $card_array[$key]['card_url'] = $card_url;
          $card_array[$key]['card_meta_description'] = $card_meta_description;
        }

        $variables['card_array'] = $card_array;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the minimal code necessary to loop through the referenced entities and get a node from a single value field on the second level:

```
if ($paragraph->getType() == 'card_grid') {
  $cards = $paragraph->field_select_card_type->referencedEntities();
  foreach ($cards as $key => $card) {
    $node = $card->field_select_a_page->entity; 
    if ($node) {
      // work with $node
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I ran through the code again and realized it is indeed working to add the values to my custom array.  I now just need to figure out how to loop the values in twig.  I've updated my question.

Comment: Please don't change the topic of the question, ask a new one. But first read https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Drupal question, it's a PHP question, but at a glance, I'd say it's because you are overwriting the `$variables['card_array']` on each loop instead of adding to it. You probably want this:

`$variables['card_array'][] = $card_array;`